# How to send crawler data to PHP via command line?

Tags: web-crawler, import.io

Can I send the results rather than stored in the JSON file, send it to PHP?

I have this two files

settings.json

```
{
"outputFile" : "C:\\wamp\\www\\drestip\\admin\\crawls\\mimshoes.json",
"logFile" : "C:\\wamp\\www\\drestip\\admin\\crawls\\mimshoes.tsv",
"pause" : 1,
"local" : false,
"connections" : 3,
"cookiesEnabled" : false,
"robotsDisabled" : false,
"advancedMode" : true,
"crawlTemplate" : [ "www.mimshoes.com/" ],
"startUrls" : [ PAGES ],
"maxDepth" : 10,
"dataTemplate" : [ "www.mimshoes.com/{alpha}-{alpha}_{alpha}-{alpha}$" ],
"destination" : "JSON",
"connectorGuid" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"canonicalDisabled" : false
}
```

user.json

```
{
"userGuid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"apiKey": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

Command line :

```
C:\Users\creatingweb03\AppData\Roaming\import.io\import.ioc.exe -crawl settings.json user.json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the "target" parameter in your settings.json, you can POST the results directly to an API endpoint.

```
// The url that crawled data will be HTTP POSTed to
"target" : "http://localhost:9200/index/datatype",
```

Theres more information here:

[import.io command-line crawler](http://support.import.io/knowledgebase/articles/325728-command-line-crawling)